# Transform row name into column name and also sum & show the data datewise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to write a query for below problem.

I want to transform row names into column name and also sum & show the data datewise

Example:

| NAME | Start Date Time | End Date time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Noida | 06-03-2020 06:30 | 06-03-2020 07:30 |
| Noida | 07-03-2020 08:54 | 07-03-2020 09:45 |
| Noida | 06-03-2020 03:30 | 06-03-2020 05:30 |
| Noida | 08-03-2020 04:55 | 08-03-2020 06:30 |
| Delhi | 08-03-2020 04:40 | 08-03-2020 05:30 |
| Delhi | 14-03-2020 04:40 | 14-03-2020 05:30 |

Now what we have to do is:
Return date wise data then sum the total time of that date i.e. name wise and row 'name' is transform into column name and if data of any date is not available then write 'No data'.

**Expected result will be:**

| Date_Wise | Noida_total_ Time | Delhi_total_ Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06-03-2020 | 03:00:00 | No data |
| 07-03-2020 | 00:51:00 | No data |
| 08-03-2020 | 01:35:00 | 00:50:00 |
| 14-03-2020 | No data | 00:50:00 |

•   First row: date is 6/03/2020 then sum of Noida total Time taken and then delhi doesn't have any data for date 6/03/2020 so we write 'No Data'.

Similarly for all rows.

Comment: What if an entry spans more than one day? For example, a start date of `2020-03-06 09:00` and an end date of `2020-03-07 05:00`?

Comment: then include it according to start date .. like in your example total time between them is 20 hours on date  2020-03-06 .

Answer (score 1):

We can use a calendar table approach here:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.NAME = 'Noida' 
             THEN DATEDIFF(hour, [Start Date Time], [End Date Time]) ELSE 0
        END) AS Noida_total_Time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.NAME = 'Delhi' 
             THEN DATEDIFF(hour, [Start Date Time], [End Date Time]) ELSE 0
        END) AS Delhi_total_Time
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CAST([Start Date Time] AS date) AS Date_Wise FROM yourTable) d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.Date_Wise = CAST(t.[Start Date Time] AS date)
GROUP BY
    d.Date_Wise
ORDER BY
    d.Date_Wise;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `SUM` instead of `MAX` though? It looks like OP wants the total # of hours for each day.

Comment: @Zack I agree with your comment and have edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
declare
    @t table ([NAME] varchar (100), [Start Date Time] datetime, [End DAte time] datetime)   

declare
    @t2 table (rn int, dates date)

declare
    @t_res table (Date_Wise date, [Noida_total_ Time] varchar (100), [Delhi_total_ Time] varchar (100))

declare
    @i int=1, @d date

insert @t  
select 'Noida', convert(datetime, '06-03-2020 06:30', 105), convert(datetime, '06-03-2020 07:30' , 105)
union all
select 'Noida', convert(datetime, '07-03-2020 08:54' , 105),    convert(datetime, '07-03-2020 09:45' , 105)
union all
select 'Noida', convert(datetime, '06-03-2020 03:30' , 105),    convert(datetime, '06-03-2020 05:30' , 105)
union all
select 'Noida', convert(datetime, '08-03-2020 04:55' , 105),    convert(datetime, '08-03-2020 06:30' , 105)
union all
select 'Delhi', convert(datetime, '08-03-2020 04:40' , 105),    convert(datetime, '08-03-2020 05:30' , 105)
union all
select 'Delhi', convert(datetime, '14-03-2020 04:40' , 105),    convert(datetime, '14-03-2020 05:30' , 105)

insert into @t2
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select dates)), dates from (
    select distinct cast([Start Date Time] as date) dates from @t
    union
    select distinct cast([End DAte time] as date) from @t
    )t

declare
    @dur_n time
    ,@dur_d time
    

while @i<=(select max(rn) from @t2 )
begin
    select @d=dates from @t2 where rn=@i

    select @dur_n=CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, datediff(ss, min(t), max(t)) * 1000, 0), 114)
    from (
        select [Start Date Time] t from @t where cast([Start Date Time] as date) =@d and [NAME]='Noida'
        union all
        select [End DAte time] t from @t where cast([End DAte time]  as date) =@d and [NAME]='Noida'
    )t1


    select @dur_d=CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, datediff(ss, min(t), max(t)) * 1000, 0), 114)
    from (
        select [Start Date Time] t from @t where cast([Start Date Time] as date) =@d and [NAME]='Delhi'
        union all
        select [End DAte time] t from @t where cast([End DAte time]  as date) =@d and [NAME]='Delhi'
    )t1


    set @i=@i+1

    insert into @t_res
    select @d, isnull(cast(@dur_n as varchar(100)), 'No data'), isnull(cast(@dur_d as varchar(100)), 'No data')
end

select * from  @t_res
```

Comment: Who put the dislike, could you share a comment on what is not the correct solution?